# In a given vector space V the zero vector is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I am trying to attempt the proof for the above theorem from my book. I want to know if my approach is correct.

Attempt:

Let 0 and **0** be additive identities

0+v=v (eq1)

**0**+v=v (eq 2)

setting eq1=eq2

0+v=**0**+v

0+v+(-v)=**0**+v+(-v)

0+**0**=**0**+**0**

0=**0**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually true for any group, which vector spaces are a particular instance of. The proof is actually a very simple one liner.

If $e_1$ and $e_2$ are zeroes, then $e_1=e_1+e_2=e_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that what you've done is *wrong*, but it isn't the best way to go about it. You are actually dangerously close to the regular proof—it's actually hidden inside yours—which would go as follows.

Let $0$ and $\textbf{0}$ be zero vectors, then

\begin{align}
0 &= 0+\textbf{0}\qquad \text{by definition of $\textbf{0}$ being a zero vector} \\
\textbf{0} &= 0+\textbf{0}\qquad \text{by definition of $0$ being a zero vector}
\end{align}

So then by transitivity, $0 = \textbf{0}$ so they are indeed the same.